# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2, tried to fix the formatting but did not work jGRASP

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am trying to make a program which averages two numbers.

```
public class Average
{
   private double one, two, average;
   public void setNums(double num1, double num2)
    {
      one=num1;
      two=num2;
    }

    public void average( )
    {
      average = (one + two) / 2;

    }
    public void print()
    {
      System.out.print( one+" + "+two +"has an average of ");
      System.out.printf("%.2d\n",average);
    }
}
```

This is the error that comes out, I assume that its due to the formatting.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkInteger(Formatter.java:3138)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2874)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2713)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
at Average.print(Average.java:26)
at AverageRunner.main(AverageRunner.java:17)
----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.

Help pls.

Also, it compiles fine but inside the main method it will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
  System.out.printf("%.2d\n",average);
```

"%.2d\n" is a malformed format string for double. Replace it with "%.2f\n"

Comment: Thanks! You were right, can't upvote due to rep D:

Comment: Great glad I could help! You should be able to accept the answer even though you can't upvote. Happy coding!